# SVN best practices for project with lost revisions

Tags: svn, tags, branch

History:
  I was asked to edit some code.  Problem is no one can find the code we're running.  So far the closest we got was a jar (containing only .class files).  I tried decompiling with JAD and had problems.  Then I tried decompiling with JADRetro then JAD (this worked better, so far I only see one problem... but I still worry about how accurate the code is).
  For future efforts I'd like to put the "code" into SVN.  But I'm wondering how best to do it.  I have this decompiled code (missing all comments, of unknown quality) AND I have actual source code of a much earlier version (which we aren't actually running).

Question:
   How best would I put code into SVN given that one version is good pristine source with comments, but is rather old (and not what we're running); and another version which doesn't recompile correctly (because of at least one decompilation error) and lacks any comments (being decompiled) but is what we are running (sort of, since it didn't decompile correctly).

I can check in the pristine code, but then how do I check in the "next version" (which is decompiled code from a later point and has LOTS of changes (classes added, code changed, classes renamed, classes moved....)).  If I check the first version in, then delete everything and check the next version in (because I'm not coding either of these versions) I worry that this will confuse/corrupt SVN.  What is the best approach for dealing with forensic revisions like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to check in decompiled code as "next version". Yes, there will be lots of changes, but there will be lots of changes anyway.

However, SVN will contain whole project history. Yes, there will be a gap in the history, but anyways, SVN is used to track history. So deleting old versions and starting from beginning is not an option.

Comment: I don't understand how I would do this.  Typically you check in code and make changes.  Here I have two "snapshots".  How do I check in the second snapshot?  I'm not doing edits, adds, deletes, moves, renames between the two versions.  That's why I mentioned checkin, delete everything, checkin again (I know that's evil).

Comment: I assume, you have the same directory structure and the same file names. Then you can simply checkin, overwrite old files with new ones and then checkout them back to SVN. But, if even file names are different - then yes, checkin, delete all, copy new files and checkout.

Comment: The problem is your assumption is wrong.  The directory structure is mostly the same, but not completely, same with filenames...  It's a royal pain.  I guess for the ones that don't change position/name I could do an mv (stomping the old "version" with the newer snapshot) and checkin the new version.